# Google script add on authorization request notice screen has a blank app name field in the test mode

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, add-on

I am working with app script. I've made a add on for google spreadsheet and I test it as "Test as add-on..."
When the add-on is first activated, Google Sheets will prompt the user to authorize. The dialog displayed by Google contains an empty string for the name of the add-on, which should be "my_add_on_name":

[image]

Might be it will be filled after publishing in the store, but I have not found evidences yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I create new add-on to try what you have experienced with this. I think aside from doing this to test your add-on, **Publish > Test as add-on**, you can also try to test your application by simply **reloading(refresh the page)** the Spreadsheet in where you create add-on. By doing this, you will see your file name in the authorization process like this.

[image]

In my case I name the file **ken_di**

Now for the process **Publish > Test as add-on**, I also receive the Authorization with empty strings.

[image]

But if you continue this one, the next page will show the name that you use for this file.

[image]

So my conclusion is, it is ok if you go with this process, I think it will not affect your application once it is published.